# keras autoencoder cnn not training

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm working on a neural network and one of the pieces I want to use is an autoencoder. However for some reason the training losses remain stuck at around 600.000 which is roughly equivalent to a loss of about 0.5 per pixel which seems to heavily indicate that no learning is taking place and that the results are somehow completly random/always the same. Anybody notice what I'm doing wrong?

Full code:

```
import tensorflow
import keras
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random 
import os
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Dropout, BatchNormalization, Input, Reshape, Flatten, Conv2DTranspose, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU
from keras.optimizers import Adam

TrainingDirectory="trainingdata" 
modelPath = "models/autoencoder1"

def main():
    model = make_model()
    model.fit_generator(mygenerator(),steps_per_epoch=2000,epochs=5)
    model.save(modelPath)
    

#ENCODER
def make_model():
    input_layer = Input(shape=(None,None, 3))
    
    # encoder
    h = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_layer)
    h = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(h)
        
    # decoder
    h = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(h)
    h = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(h)
    output_layer = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(h)   
    
    #assemble network
    ae = Model(input_layer, output_layer)
    ae.summary()
    ae.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mse")
    return ae
def Preprocess(image):
     resized_image = scale_down(image)
     return resized_image

def scale_down(image):
    max_size= max(image.shape)
    scale=1;
    if(max_size>750):
        scale=750/max_size
    width = int(image.shape[1] * scale)
    height = int(image.shape[0] * scale)
    if width%72!=0:
        width=width+(72-width%72)
    if height%72!=0:
        height=height+(72-height%72)
    dsize = (width, height)
    image=cv2.resize(image, dsize)
    return image
     
def mygenerator():
    
    batch_features=None
    batch_labels=None
    while True:
        target=random.choice(os.listdir(TrainingDirectory))
        print(target)
        batch_features=Preprocess(cv2.imread(TrainingDirectory+'/'+target+"/input.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR))
        batch_labels=Preprocess(cv2.imread(TrainingDirectory+'/'+target+"/labelWalls.png", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR))
        print(batch_features.shape)
        yield np.array([batch_features]), np.array([batch_features])
main()
```

Comment: I'm open to suggestions on how to improve this question (adding extra information etc.) or general hints if you notice something bad in this code.

Comment: You can test to see if its an architectural issue/limit by training on a single image/batch and seeing if it overfits or not. If it is not architectural, then it is likely your training problem is more difficult than your training method or architecture can handle

Comment: Did you check that your data values are in 0 to 1?  Since your output layer has sigmoid activation, it does not produce value not in the range.  I'm sorry if I missed something.

Comment: @KotaMori thank you! that was indeed the problem, the images were scale on a 0-255 range so that failed. Now I feel a bit stupid